# Labeling a US States map

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2

I made a map in R and was wondering how to label the States Codes (variable which is in my dataset) appropriately. Using the simple geom_text or even geom_text_repel I get a lot of labels for each State (I can actually understand why), as I proceed to show:

[Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfYNa.png)

How can I solve it so each State gets 1 and only 1 text abbreviation (these State Codes are in my dataset as a variable under the name `State Codes`)? Thanks in advance.

Code below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(maps)
library(wesanderson)
library(hrbrthemes)

ggplot(data = data, 
       mapping = aes(x = long, 
                     y = lat, 
                     group = group, 
                     fill = black_percentage)) +
  geom_polygon(col = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(label = black_percentage)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, family = "Times", face = "bold"),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5, family = "Times", face = "italic"),
        plot.caption = element_text(family = "Times", face = "italic"),
        legend.key.height = unit(0.85, "cm"),
        legend.key.width = unit(0.85, "cm")) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "#E6A0C4", 
                       high = "#7294D4") +
  labs(title = "Percentage of Black People, US States 2018",
       subtitle = "Pink colors represent lower percentages. Light-blue colors represents higer percentages") +
  ggsave("failed_map.png")
```

Comment: I kinda messed up here labeling the variable "black_percentage" instead of "`State Codes`" as I said I wanted, but this map was made only for demonstrating purposes. Still not working when properly labeled.

Comment: Can you provide the/some sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you provide the/some sample data?

One possible reason for multiple labels is that each state has multiple rows in the data, so `ggplot` thinks it needs to plot multiple labels. If you only need a single label, a solution is to create a separate summary dataset, which has only one row for each state/label. You then provide this summary data to `geom_text()` rather than the original data. Although not the problem in this instance, this is a solution to the common problem of 'blurry' labels; when 10's or 100's of labels are printed on top of one another they appear blurry, but when a single label is printed it appears fine.

Looking at your code and mapping aesthetics, it looks like `geom_text()` is inheriting the `x` and `y` aesthetics from the first `ggplot()` line. Therefore `geom_text()` will make a label for every value of `x` and `y` (`long` and `lat`) per state. This also explains why the labels all appear to follow the state borders.

I would suggest that you summarise each state to a single (`x`, `y`) coordinate (e.g. the middle of the state), and give this to `geom_text()`. Again, without some sample data it may be hard to explain, but something like:

```
# make the summary label dataframe
state_labels <- your_data %>%
   group_by(state) %>%
   summarise(
      long = mean(long), 
      lat = mean(lat), 
      mean_black = mean(black_percentage)
   )


# then we plot it
ggplot(data = data, 
       mapping = aes(x = long, 
                     y = lat, 
                     group = group, 
                     fill = black_percentage)) +
  geom_polygon(col = "black") +
  geom_text(data = state_labels, aes(label = mean_black))
```

As the name of the `x` and `y` coords are the same in your `data` and the new `state_labels` summary we made (`long` and `lat`), `geom_text()` will 'inherit' (assume/use) the same `x` and `y` aesthetics that you supplied inside the first line of `ggplot()`. This is convenient, but sometimes can cause you grief if either dataset has different/the same column names or you want to assign different aesthetics. For example, you don't need `geom_text()` to inherit the `fill = black_percentage` aesthetic (although in this instance I don't think it will cause a problem, as `geom_text()` doesn't accept a `fill` aesthetic). To disable aesthetic inheritance, simply provide `inherit.aes = FALSE` to the `geom`. In this instance, it would look like this, note how we now provide `geom_text()` with `x` and `y` aesthetics.

```
ggplot(data = data, 
       mapping = aes(x = long, 
                     y = lat, 
                     group = group, 
                     fill = black_percentage)) +
  geom_polygon(col = "black") +
  geom_text(data = state_labels, aes(x = long, y = lat, label = mean_black), inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

**EDIT** If you want a single label, but the label is not a numeric value and you can't calculate a summary statistic using `mean` or similar, then the same principles apply; you want to create a summarised version of the data, with a single coordinates for each state and a single label - 1 row for each state. There's many ways to do this, but my go-to would be something like `dplyr::first` or similar.

```
# make the summary label dataframe
state_labels <- your_data %>%
   group_by(state) %>%
   summarise(
      long = mean(long), 
      lat = mean(lat), 
      my_label = first(`State Codes`)
   )



# then we plot it
ggplot(data = data, 
       mapping = aes(x = long, 
                     y = lat, 
                     group = group, 
                     fill = black_percentage)) +
  geom_polygon(col = "black") +
  geom_text(data = state_labels, aes(label = my_label))
```

Finally, `ggplot` has several built-in functions to plot and map spatial data. It is a good idea to use these where possible, as it will make your life a lot easier. A great 3-part tutorial can be found [here](https://r-spatial.org/r/2018/10/25/ggplot2-sf.html), and it even includes an example of exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: That was exactly my point, and that's why I said that I could actually understand why I was getting multiple labels. When creating a map, States (in this cases, but whatever you're plotting) get multiple latitude and longitud numbers.
Thanks a lot for the code and the responde, gonna check it ASAP. And thanks for the tutorial, will see it.

Comment: Actually, sorry, I was trying to label State's abbreviations, not State's percentage of black people. I think that changes the whole perspective, doesn't it? 
I don't actually know how to do it, then, because, as oppose to the percentage, I cannot calculate a mean value. So how do we proceed? Ha. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Updated the answer, hopefully this helps

Comment: Worked just fine ;). Now having trouble with labels positions, ha. Thanks man, appreciate it.

Comment: Awesome. You can adjust individual label positions using `geom_text(hjust = c(...), vjust = c(....))`. You can supply a single number to `hjust` and `vjust` to adjust all labels the same, or supply a vector of values specifying individual adjustments for each label. It would be appreciated if you accept the answer if it worked too :)

Comment: It'll work. Data is just a little messy, so It'll take some time as well. Was just for practicing and fun purposes, though. I can't thank you enough, really appreciate you taking the time. As a bonus, I just posted some question I had about making a scatter plot with some discontinued data, just in case you find the time to check it out. Link is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68900583/scatter-plot-with-variables-that-have-multiple-different-years (sorry for spamming). I might as well make you my teacher, ha. But jokes out, thanks again.