# Scatter plot with variables that have multiple different years

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm currently trying to make a scatter plot of child mortality rate and child labor. My problem is, I don't actually have a lot of data, and some countries may only get values for some years, and some other countries may only have data for some other years, so I can't plot all the data together, nor the data in any year is big enough to limit to  that only year. I was wondering if there is a function that takes the **last** value available in the dataset for any given specified variable. So, for instance, if my last data for child labor from Germany is from 2015 and my last data from Italy is from 2014, and so forth with the rest of the countries, *is there a way I can plot the last values for each country*?

Code goes like this:

```
head(data2)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  Entity      Code   Year mortality labor
  <chr>       <chr> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 Afghanistan AFG    1962      34.5    NA
2 Afghanistan AFG    1963      33.9    NA
3 Afghanistan AFG    1964      33.3    NA
4 Afghanistan AFG    1965      32.8    NA
5 Afghanistan AFG    1966      32.2    NA
6 Afghanistan AFG    1967      31.7    NA
```

Never mind about those NA's. Labor data just doesn't go back there. But I do have it in the dataset, for more recent years. Child mortality data, on the other hand, is actually pretty complete.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to define what you mean by 'last' value per group - as in most recent, last occurrence in the data or something else?

`dplyr::last` picks out the last occurrence in the data, so you could use it along with `arrange` to order your data. In this example we sort the data by `Year` (ascending order by default), so the last observation will be the most recent. Assuming you don't want to include `NA` values, we also use `filter` to remove them from the data.

```
data2 %>%

   # first remove NAs from the data
   filter(
      !is.na(labor)
   ) %>%

   # then sort the data by Year
   arrange(Year) %>%

   # then extract the last observation per country
   group_by(Entity) %>%
   summarise(
      last_record = last(labor)
   )
```

Comment: Yes, I wanted the data to be as recent as possible. As I said, if I had child data from 2014 for Germany and 2015 for Italy (dataset also has older data, of course, but might have forgotten to mention that part), those are the values I want to plot. 
And once again, your solution worked. Thanks *a lot*.

Comment: Let me just add: now I'm trying to include a linear regression line with ```geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x,  method = "lm", col = "black",  alpha = 0, linetype = "dashed")``` but nothing will show up. Any idea why?

Comment: I couldn't say without seeing what else is in your code. I would  recommend checking out "R for Data Science" https://r4ds.had.co.nz/index.html. Particularly in this case Chapter 3 Data Visualisation and Chapter 5 Data transformation.

Comment: I can let you take a look.

`str(data2)  
spec_tbl_df[,5] [11,945 × 5] (S3: spec_tbl_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Entity   : chr [1:11945] "Afghanistan" "Afghanistan" "Afghanistan" "Afghanistan" ...
 $ Code     : chr [1:11945] "AFG" "AFG" "AFG" "AFG" ...
 $ Year     : num [1:11945] 1962 1963 1964 1965 1966 ...
 $ mortality: num [1:11945] 34.5 33.9 33.3 32.8 32.2 ...
 $ labor    : num [1:11945] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...`

Will read that book! Just waiting to see if I can get my hands on a physical version of it as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find which variable to plot, but following code can select only last of each country.

```
    data2 %>%
      group_by(Entity) %>%
      filter(Year == max(Year)) %>% 
      ungroup
```

result is like

```
      Entity      Code   Year mortality labor
      <chr>       <chr> <dbl>     <dbl> <lgl>
    1 Afghanistan AFG    1967      31.7 NA
```

No you can plot some variable.

Comment: Sorry for not giving variable names. Problem with what you propose is that one of the variables reach out much further than the other, so filtering by maximum year will just filter *every* variable to that year, and, as I said, I don't have that data. I'm looking for something flexible (if there's anything). I need each variable to accommodate to it's last year, not just one general. But thank you very much for responding. Appreciate it.

Comment: @Gaspar Do you need to get every variable with last year at one time? Or it's acceptable that select last variable per each variables?

Comment: By using `group_by(Entity)`, it will keep only the maximum value for year, _per Entity (country)_, so it should work as you want.